# Having trouble using find() on selenium's webdriver.page_source() method

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

My code is:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from selenium import webdriver
first_page_url = 'https://store.steampowered.com/tags/en/Action/#p=0&tab=NewReleases'
first_url = 'https://store.steampowered.com/tags/en/Action/#p='
rest_url = '&tab=NewReleases'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(first_page_url)
soup_page = driver.page_source
print(type(soup_page))
page_numbers = soup_page.find('div',{'id':'NewReleases_ctn'})
print(page_numbers)
```

when I print `soup_page`'s type, it gives string, but when I try applying find() or find_all() method, it gives the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "new_steam.py", line 13, in <module>
    page_numbers = soup_page.find('div',{'id':'NewReleases_ctn'})
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

Please help me out here. Im new to web scraping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you haven't converted `page_source` into `bs4` object. You first need to form `bs4` object to use its features. So in your case:

```
# Since you are calling BeautifulSoup as soup
soup_page = soup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
```

Rest should work with no problem if you are grabbing correct tags.

Answer (score 0):

```
str.find(str, beg=0, end=len(string))
```

This is the syntax of fine where beg and end is the start and end index within which the string need to be searched

you are using it as :

```
str.find(str,dict)
```

which is not supported , it should be something like

```
soup_page.find(stringyouwanttosearch,int,int)
```

Comment: What if I want to search for an HTML element?

Comment: page_source returns the string representation  , so search for string.find("<div asdasd>somehting</div>")

Comment: So how can I find: 'div','id'='NewReleases_ctn' and the content that is contained inside of it?